# Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null for iframes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following script to create an iframe

```
  function createIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.style.position = "absolute";
    iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    // Firefox, Opera
    if(iframe.contentDocument) iframe.doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    // Internet Explorer
    else if(iframe.contentWindow) iframe.doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

    // Magic: Force creation of the body (which is null by default in IE).
    // Also force the styles of visited/not-visted links.
    iframe.doc.open();
    iframe.doc.write('<style>');
    iframe.doc.write("a{color: #000000; display:none;}");   
    iframe.doc.write("a:visited {color: #FF0000; display:inline;}");    
    iframe.doc.write('</style>');
    iframe.doc.close();

    // Return the iframe: iframe.doc contains the iframe.
    return iframe;
  }
```

however in chrome console it is giving me the error Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

why is it not working?

Comment: When do you get the error? I ran it in my Chrome console,it worked!Just check if ` document.createElement("iframe");` returns an element!

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. Have you added body in the page?

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
   createIframe()
};
function createIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.style.position = "absolute";
    iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    // Firefox, Opera
    if(iframe.contentDocument) iframe.doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    // Internet Explorer
    else if(iframe.contentWindow) iframe.doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

    // Magic: Force creation of the body (which is null by default in IE).
    // Also force the styles of visited/not-visted links.
    iframe.doc.open();
    iframe.doc.write('<style>');
    iframe.doc.write("a{color: #000000; display:none;}");   
    iframe.doc.write("a:visited {color: #FF0000; display:inline;}");    
    iframe.doc.write('</style>');
    iframe.doc.close();

    // Return the iframe: iframe.doc contains the iframe.
    return iframe;
  }  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.doc.write is not the cleanest solution....